# Python threads repeating task twice instead of two differing tasks

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently writing a program that loops through a list of card numbers and then calls functions with those card numbers. I wrote some basic python threading code that looped through the list that is obtained from the cards.txt file, and then spawned a user defined amount of threads. However, this is producing behavior I dont like because it is just spawning the threads with the same card number. I can see why this is happening because the for loop is underneath the card loop, causing it to take in the same card number. However, I am not sure how to fix this. I looked into thread pools but that still doesnt solve my issue because the for loops are still nested. Here is some relevant code, any help is greatly appreciated

```
for card in cards:
    threads = []
    card = card.strip()
    for i in range(threads2):
        x = threading.Thread(target=exampleFunct, args=(card,))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Once again I can see why running the for loop inside of the `for card in cards:` is producing this behavior but I can't see a way out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it's the order of the threads. One option would be to spawn all the threads ahead of time and then use a queue or similar to send them work. Something like this:

```
import threading
import queue

cards = ["5\n", "32", "56", "34\n"]
thread_count = 2


def exampleFunct(q):
    while True:
        print('Thread waiting for card and int')
        card_and_int = q.get()
        if card_and_int is None:
            print('That means we are all done')
            break
        card, number = card_and_int
        print("card {}, number {}".format(card, number))


q = queue.Queue()
threads = []
for i in range(thread_count):
    t = threading.Thread(target=exampleFunct, args=(q,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for i, card in enumerate(cards):
    card = card.strip()
    q.put((card, i))
    
# Stop all the threads
for i in range(thread_count):
    q.put(None)

# and wait for them to exit
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the problem but I wonder if you can explain a little more what you are trying to accomplish.  I made some code that will function on its own and maybe this will help.

```
cards = ["5\n", "32", "56", "34\n"]
threads2 = 2


def exampleFunct(card: str, number: int):
    print("card {}, number {}".format(card, number))


for card in cards:
    threads = []
    card = card.strip()
    for i in range(threads2):
        x = threading.Thread(target=exampleFunct, args=(card, i))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

print("done")
```

the output is below and it does cycle through the card numbers

```
card 5, number 0
card 5, number 1
card 32, number 0
card 32, number 1
card 56, number 0
card 56, number 1
card 34, number 0
card 34, number 1
done
```

Comment: I think he wants to process each card once. Your code is having each thread process the _same_ card. It's also spawning `thread2` new threads for each loop and I suspect OP intended for there to be `thread2` threads _total_ that cooperate to process each card exactly once. Not 100% sure about that but that would seem to be the more common pattern.